# config.get not working in python -pycharm

Tags: python, config

config.ini file

```
[info]
baseURL = https://admin-demo.nopcommerce.com/
username = admin@yourstore.com
password = admin
```

readprop file

```
import configparser
import os
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
ini_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'config.ini')
config.read(ini_path)
url = config.get('info', 'baseURL')
print(url)
```

Error
ERROR testCases/test_login.py - configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'info'

Trying to read config file
it's giving error
ERROR testCases/test_login.py - configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'info'

Comment: Your code works for me. Are you sure that `config.ini` is in the directory you are running the script from?

Comment: `config.ini` is not in the current directory.  `print(os.getcwd())` to see what the current directory is.

Comment: Side comment -- using `os.getcwd()` is useless here, because it will look in the current directory by default anyway.